# Visio Drawing Control in VB.net

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, visio

The Visio Drawing Control was successfully added into a form in VB.net. The issue faced was how can I display the 'Shapes' window. I checked the child for Microsoft.Office.Interop.Visio.Window and don't see any to display the 'Shapes' window.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In VB.net, to show the 'Shapes' window at the Microsoft Visio Drawing Control:

```vb
Dim vsoWindow As Visio.Window

vsoWindow = AxDrawingControl1.Window
vsoWindow.Application.DoCmd(1669)
```

Answer (score 1):

In VBA you can show Shapes window with docmd

> Application.DoCmd (visCmdShapesWindow) ' visCmdShapesWindow = 1669

Full DOCMD commands list you can find there
[DoCmd/DOCMD Commands](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Visio-VBA/articles/docmd-docmd-commands)

Comment: Although it was for VBA but still was a really useful information. Thank you.